# If $a-b\le c<\infty$ then $a<\infty$

Tags: real-numbers

Given arbitrary $a,b$ in the extended reals do we really know that;

If $a-b\le c<\infty$ then $a<\infty$

Comment: Add $b$, that should do it

Comment: @M.Nestor and if b is infinite?

Comment: [Sure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line). If $a=\infty$ then, since $\infty - \infty$ is not defined, be would have that $b\neq \infty$ and, by axioms of the extended reals, $a-b=\infty + (-b) = \infty$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the variable $c$, the problem is equivalent to if $a-b<\infty$ implies $a<\infty$. Note that $a<\infty$ is equivalent to $a\neq\infty$, so for the proof it is sufficient to suppose $a=\infty$ and obtain a contradiction.

Suppose $a-b<\infty$, and consider three cases.

Case 1. If $b\in\mathbb{R}$, then add $b$ to the inequality:

$$a-b<\infty \implies a<\infty+b=\infty$$

Case 2. If $b=-\infty$, the assumption is

$$a+\infty<\infty$$

which has no solution in the extended reals. If by contradiction $a=\infty$ then we have $\infty+\infty<\infty$, or simply $\infty<\infty$, a contradiction.

Case 3. If $b=+\infty$, the assumption is

$$a-\infty <\infty$$

If by contradiction $a=\infty$, then the left side is indeterminate, a contradiction.